# Suspend barcode scanner in Zebra TC51

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism, barcode-scanner

I'm developing an application with Xamarin Forms and Prism. I'm using Zebra [SDK](http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-xamarin/latest/api/) to use barcode scanner hardware.
I intercept the barcode scanning event with the MessagingCenter, I have the Send declaration in the MainActivity.cs:

```
Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send<App, string>(_my_application, "Barcode", data.Data);
```

and I receive the scanned data in ViewModels with the subscription:

```
Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, string>(this, "Barcode", (sender, arg) =>
                {
...

}
```

Now I need to stop the barcode scanner in case of functional errors. I usually show a pop-up message:

```
_pageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Barcode Scanner", "My message", "OK");
```

and I want to enable again the scanner after that the user touch the "ok" button. (I want that this is a blocking message)
How I can do that? The problem is that my barcode scanner code is in the MainActivity and I don't know how I can stop and resume the barcode scanner from the ViewModel code. The pop-up message is not enough because the scanner is triggered by the hardware button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple solution is to use a boolean variable "isScannerWorking".

In your Subscribe check isScannerWorking value

```
Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, string>(this, "Barcode", (sender, arg) =>
                {
    if(isScannerWorking){

         // do something
    }

}
```

Set "isScannerWorking" to false before your `_pageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Barcode Scanner", "My message", "OK");`and set to true after the DisplayAlertAsync. In this way, your scanner continue to read barcode but it does not use it.

Otherwise I think you have to use DependencyService to call some SDK function to disable the scanner.

Comment: Hi Alessandro, I think that the boolean variable as workaround is a good solution but the "beep" sound of the scan remains. How can I mute this sound? Otherwise, the DependencyService solution can be good for me, I use DependencyService for other functions (e.g. ISQLite). But I don't know how to structure a DependencyService for barcode scanner with Zebra SDK. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have take a look to http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/4-2/tutorial/tutBasicScanningAPI/ It seems there is a scanner.disable . I think you can try to use this property with a dependencyservice

Answer (score 0):

For starters stop using Messaging Center... you can and should instead use `IEventAggregator`. Remember that the Container is a public property of your App so you can actually use it to resolve dependencies like the `IEventAggregator` from platform code like:

```
// Remember that you may have an Application class already in scope 
// in the platform and may need to fully qualify the XF Application
var app = (App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current;
var eventAggregator = app.Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
```

To use `IEventAggregator` you will need to create events that make sense for your application. These can contain a payload or not depending on your need.

```
// An event with no payload
public class FooEventA : PubSubEvent { }

// An event with a string payload
public class FooEventB : PubSubEvent<string> { }
```

You can then publish and subscribe as follows:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<FooEventB>().Publish("Some Payload");

eventAggregator.GetEvent<FooEventB>().Subscribe(OnFooEventBPublished);

private void OnFooEventBPublished(string payload)
{
   // Do stuff
}
```